# Dynamically storing information from a file using C

Tags: c, pointers, char, realloc, memset

I'm new to C and trying to learn a few things. What I'm trying to do is read in a file and store the information. Since the format will be a CSV, the plan is to read in each character, determine if its a number or a comma, and store the numbers in a linked list. The problem I'm having is reading in numbers that are more than one character long like the following example.

5,2,24,5

Here's the code I've got so far and its just not giving back output that I expect. Here's the code, and the output is below the code sample.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct list {
  float value;
  struct list * next;
  struct list * prev;
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
  FILE *infile;
  char *token = NULL;
  char  my_char;

  /* Open the file. */
  // The file name should be in argv[1]
  if((infile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error Opening File.\n");
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  while((my_char = (char)fgetc(infile)) != EOF){
    //Is my_char a number?
    if(isdigit(my_char)){
      if(token == NULL){
        token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        memset(token, '\0', 1);
        strcpy(token, &my_char);
        printf("length of token -> %d\n", strlen(token));
        printf("%c\n", *token);
      } else {
        token = (char *)realloc(token, sizeof(token) + 1);
        strcat(token, &my_char);
        printf("%s\n", token);
      }
    }
  }

  free(token);
  fclose(infile);
}
```

And here is the output:

```
[estest@THEcomputer KernelFunctions]$ nvcc linear_kernel.cu -o linear_kernel.exe
[estest@THEcomputer KernelFunctions]$ ./linear_kernel.exe iris.csv
length of token -> 5
5
5a#1a#
5a#1a#3a#
5a#1a#3a#5a#
5a#1a#3a#5a#1a#
5a#1a#3a#5a#1a#4a#
*** glibc detected *** ./linear_kernel.exe: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001236350 ***
```

I don't understand why the length of the token is '5' when I expect to be 1 and the strange looking characters that follow 5 (represented by 'a#'). Can anyone help me understand this a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue appears to be a problem with null terminated strings.  The `malloc` call is allocating 1 byte.  But `strcpy` copies bytes until it reaches a null terminator (a zero byte).  So the results are not well defined since the byte after `my_char` is a "random" value from the stack.

You need to allocate one byte longer (and realloc one byte longer) than the length of the string to allow for a null terminator.  And the `strcpy` and `strcat` calls are not valid for the source "string" which is actually just a character. To continue using the basic logic that you are implementing, it would be necessary to simply assign the character value to the appropriate position in the `token` array.  Alternatively, you could declare `my_char` as a two byte character array and set the second byte to a 0 terminator to allow `strcpy` and `strcat` to be used.  For example,

```
char my_char[2];
my_char[1] = '\0';
```

And then it would be necessary to change the usage of `my_char` accordingly (assign the value to `my_char[0]`, and remove the `&` in the strcpy/strcat calls).  The compiler warnings/errors would help address those changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *token = NULL;

token = (char *)realloc(token, sizeof(token) + 1);
```

`token` is a pointer.  `sizeof` doesn't give you the allocated size of the chunk of memory to which it points; it gives you the size of the pointer object itself.  Apparently pointers are 4 bytes on your system (that's typical), so you're always reallocating to 5 bytes.

Some more suggestions:

```
exit(1);
```

`exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` is more portable.

char  my_char;

```
while((my_char = (char)fgetc(infile)) != EOF){
```

`fgetc` returns an int, not a char.  The value is either the next character read from the file (represented as an unsigned char and then converted to int, so typically in the range 0..255) *or* the value `EOF` (which is typically -1).  If plain char is signed on your system, an input character that happens to be 255 will cause your loop to terminate prematurely; if plain char is unsigned, your loop may never end, because you're converting the negative value of `EOF` to a signed value.  I'm actually not 100% sure what happens in the latter case, but it doesn't matter; make `my_char` an int.

```
token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Don't cast the result of `malloc()`.  It's not necessary (`malloc()` returns a `void*` so it can be converted implicitly), and it can hide errors. `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.  Just write:

```
token = malloc(1);
```

And *always* check the return value; `malloc()` returns NULL on failure.

```
memset(token, '\0', 1);
```

Simpler: `*token = '\0';`

Allocating a single byte, then `realloc()`ating one additional byte at a time, is likely to be terribly inefficient.

```
strcat(token, &my_char);
```

The second argument to `strcat()` must be a pointer to a string.  `&my_char` is of the right type, but if the byte following `my_char` in memory doesn't happen to be a '`\0'`, `Bad Things Can Happen`.

This is not an exhaustive review.

Recommended reading: the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: I can confirm that I've seen infinite loops with code like `while((my_char = (char)fgetc(infile)) != EOF){`

Comment: I knew it was you at paragraph two! Nice breakdown, "other Keith". :)

Comment: I haven't had a problem with infinite loops though. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using nvcc instead of gcc?

Comment: @Erik: It won't cause an infinite loop unless plain char is unsigned.  But don't waste too much time worrying about the circumstances in which assigning the result of `fgetc' to a `char` happens to work.  Just fix the code to use an `int` (and drop the unnecessary cast).

Comment: @Keith: Easy enough. By the way, the link in the post is very helpful. Do you have any other recommendations for further reading on pointers and arrays? The link was helpful but I'm still not clear on this.

Comment: @Eric: Section 6 of the clc FAQ is the best reference I know of.  If you have specific questions, post them.

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating only 1 byte of data for your string in your code:

```
token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
memset(token, '\0', 1);
```

However, because you're only zeroing out one byte, your string is not necessarily null terminated.  What you're most likely seeing is extra junk that was in the memory after your char *.

Answer (score 0):

For one, it would be a lot easier for you to read 1 whole line at a time as opposed to 1 character at a time. You can then use `strtok()` to split the line by the commas.

There are a few problems with your code:

```
token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

This will only allocate 1 byte. C strings have to be null-terminated, so even a string of length 1 requires 2 bytes of allocated space.

```
strcpy(token, &my_char);
strcat(token, &my_char);
```

`my_char` is a single character, not a null-terminated string (which is what `strcpy()` and `strcat()` expect).

```
sizeof(token)
```

This is not what you mean to do. This will return you the size of a pointer (which is the type of `token`. You probably want something like `strlen()`, but you'd have to refactor your code to make sure you're using null-terminated strings as opposed to single characters.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I'm used to Java's StringTokenizer being inefficient. Does strtok() make unnecessary copies like Java's StringTokenizer?

Comment: ``strtok()`` does not make any additional copies, but it will stick ``NULL``s inside the string you give it where the separator occurs, so make sure you're not destroying the copy of the string if you mean to use it again. Also, ``strtok()`` is not threadsafe; ``strtok_r()`` is a re-entrant version that is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `my_char` should be `int` because that's what [`fgetc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) returns, using a `char` will mean that you'll never find your EOF condition:

```
int my_char;
/*...*/
while((my_char = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
```

The `EOF` value is an `int` that is not a valid `char`, that's how you can detect the end of a file while reading it one byte at a time and from the [fine manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html):

> If the integer value returned by fgetc() is stored into a variable of type char and then compared against the integer constant EOF, the comparison may never succeed, because sign-extension of a variable of type char on widening to integer is implementation-defined.

Others have pointed out your memory errors so I'll leave those alone.

Comment: Actually, the casting works fine. I'm not sure if maybe the compiler version would affect this. I'm using nvcc by the way.

Comment: @Erik: But EOF is an `int` that won't fit in in a `char` so that you can differentiate between an end-of-file and a valid byte. If it is working then you're getting lucky with your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
while((my_char = (char)fgetc(infile)) != EOF){
```

This is bad times.  `fgetc` returns `int`.  It can represent more values than `char`.  `EOF` is typically `-1`.  Since you're storing in a `char`, how do you expect to represent the character `0xff`?  You won't; you'll end up treating it as `EOF`. You should do this:

```
int c;

while ((c=fgetc(infile)) != EOF)
{
   char my_char = c;
```

Next up...

```
       token = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You should check the return value of `malloc`.  You should also consider allocating more than you need up front, otherwise every call to `realloc` could potentially have to copy the characters that you've seen so far.  You will get better algorithmic complexity by, say, making every allocation size a power of 2.  Also, unlike C++, in C you don't need to cast from `void*`.

```
       memset(token, '\0', 1);
       strcpy(token, &my_char);
```

This is not what you think it means.  `(&my_char)[1]` must be zero for this to work, so this is undefined behavior.  You should try this:

```
token[0] = my_char;
token[1] = 0;
```

Also, you only allocated 1 `char`.  You need 2 for this to work.

```
       token = (char *)realloc(token, sizeof(token) + 1);
```

`sizeof` does not magically remember how much you allocated last time, it only takes the compile-time size of the type it's specified, in this case equivalent to `sizeof(char*)` which would be 4 or 8 on 32 or 64-bit systems respectively.  You need to track the real allocation size in a variable.  Also this kind of `realloc` is prone to leak memory on failure, you should do this:

```
 void *ptr = realloc(token, new_length);
 if (!ptr) { /* TODO: handle error */ }
 token = ptr;
```

Moving on...

```
       strcat(token, &my_char);
```

This has the same undefined behavior as the last use of `&my_char` as if it was a C string.  Also, even if it did work it is wasteful, since `strcat` must traverse the entire string to find the end.

Summary of my suggestions follows:

```
int c;
size_t alloc_size = 0;
size_t current_len = 0;
char *token = NULL;
void *ptr;

while ((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF)
{
   if (is_digit(c))
   {
      if (alloc_size < current_len + 2)
      {
         if (!alloc_size)
         {
            // Set some arbitrary start size...
            //
            alloc_size = 64;
         }
         else
         {
            alloc_size *= 2;
         }

         if (!token)
            ptr = malloc(alloc_size);
         else
            ptr = realloc(token, alloc_size);

         if (!ptr)
         {
            free(token);
            return -1;
         }
      }

      token[current_len++] = c;
      token[current_len] = 0;
   }
}

/* TODO: do something with token... */

free(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `strcpy` is as simple as

```
while(*dest++ = *src++);
```

So, memory pointed by `src` is expected to end with at least one '\0' character. In your case, the single element array holds a character that's not null. Hence, `strcpy` goes beyond it's memory and ends up dereferencing outside of its segment resulting in a fault. This is not observed when a call like `strcpy(buff, "abcd")` is made because, the compiler places `abcd\0` in the code section of the program.

To solve your problem in general, using `fgetline` and `strtok` will be a better and easier way of solving it.